# Changing one value in 2D array changes whole line

Tags: javascript, arrays

Ok so in doing a simple game of life simulation I came across this really wierd problem I have a 2D array and Im trying to change one value at cords x,y simple right?

```js
let arr = new Array(10).fill(new Array(10).fill(1))
arr[1][1] = 0
console.log(arr[3])
```

I've done this in the past in multiple projects but now for some strange reason now it changes all arr[x][1] instead of just arr[1][1]

Answer (score 1):

`new Array` creates an object (almost everything in JS is object) that is used later to fill another array with **THE SAME** array (object, in fact) 10 times. So, what you are doing by `arr[1][1] = 0;` is changing object's property that gets reflected everywhere.

To prove that it is the same object everywhere in the array, try to check like `arr[4] === arr[7]` it will give you `true`.

Answer (score 1):

[Array#fill](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/fill) by definition fills up the array with the same object.

You should do this:

```
new Array(10).fill(0).map(() => new Array(10).fill(1)));
```

Comment: I think you have to use `.fill` initially as well (at least in chrome). Otherwise this will just produce an empty array with length 10.

Comment: map will skip nulls

Answer (score 1):

`new Array(10).fill(1)` generate a reference which is being used in each slot of array. So, modifying an index of any array also update others array, as they have the same reference.

```
let arr = new Array(10).fill(new Array(10).fill(1))
```

You need to create a new reference of array for each index. You can use `array#from` to generate it.

```js
const arr = Array.from({length: 10}, _ => new Array(10).fill(1));
arr[1][1] = 0
console.log(arr)
```